# Google Places Autocomplete API filter type "address" returns places of type "route" via iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-places-api, google-places, gmsplacepicker

> Google Places API for iOS version: 2.2.30010.0

Code:

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = .address
filter.country = "us"
return filter
```

When searching for example **Montrose** with filter of type **address** & country **us**, the search results display:

[image]

The country filter works, but the type filter displays results of type **route**. Is this the intended behavior?

The [Place Autocomplete docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) specify:

> `address` instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results with a **precise address**. Generally, you use this request when you know the user will be looking for a fully specified address.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what a **precise address** is, but it seems like the query should only return results with a building number ex. 22 Montrose Ave.

Is it possible to return only places that have building numbers?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a workaround for this issue? I'm seeing the same behavior using the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: @SamHanley did you find something on this matter?

Comment: No, I was able to find a couple other mentions of this on the internet, but the closest thing I found to a solution was one blog where the author [reimplemented the entire presentation component of the Autocomplete control in ES6, to work around this issue](https://chromatichq.com/blog/implementing-google-places-autocomplete-es6-part-three).

Comment: Any solution to this, please?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove filter.type = .address